# Python Pywinauto how to validate if a UI element exists using Pywinauto for Desktop application

Tags: python, user-interface, automation, pywinauto

Hello Friends I am new to PywinAuto looking for some quick Guidence
how can we validate if a UI element Exists , for example if a Test looks for specific Ui element existance we should be able to validate it , it can be anything which appears on the page of AUT.
if a dot(.) also should be validated ,how to ? or a Buttons existance should be validated . please help on this

Comment: Do you have any code or pseudo code to show your problem? There is method `.exists(timeout=2)` which returns `True` or `False`. Did you read the [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) and [Waiting for Long Operations](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wait_long_operations.html)?

Comment: @VasilyRyabov Thanks for the response, I have a requirement of validating all the UI Elements on each page of our Desktop application , that to make sure we will not miss any Element from any page and it should also be under correct tree , for eaxmple a menu should have all the required options as expected , so each time we run regression we will be validating all the UI Elements , how can we do this ? how can I create a repository Hierarchy ? and how to implement it using .exists?

Comment: Verifying all the UI elements by a hot key is a feature planned after UI recorder implementation (which is very early prototype). Given it’s hobby open source, it could be done in 3-4 years with current resources.

Comment: I apologise for not asking the precise , I have already set the benchmark of using the Pywin auto , I have installed pywinauto I have the folder structure ready , and Iam able to dump the controls to a file , and iam using inspect.exe also to identify elements , but only thing Iam unable to proceed is how can I validate if a element exists or not , really Iam looking for a code line how it should be used  for an element

Comment: Something like this: `app.window(title="Main Window").child_window(title="OK", control_type="Button").exists(timeout=2)` It's a WindowSpecification method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Iam able to progress with my validation part of Ui elements but iam getting a problem(not always out of 5 runs 3 times) which says pywinauto.timings.TimeoutError: timed out , Iam unable to get rid of it can u suggest anything?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
    dlg_spec.menu_select("Help->About")
  File "D:\FromSamina\TCX3_POC\venv\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\uiawrapper.py", line 723, in menu_select
    menu.item_by_path(path, exact).select()
  File "D:\FromSamina\TCX3_POC\venv\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\uia_controls.py", line 1060, in item_by_path
    lambda: len(self.top_level_parent().descendants(control_type="Menu")) > 0)
  File "D:\FromSamina\TCX3_POC\venv\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 375, in wait_until
    raise err
pywinauto.timings.TimeoutError: timed out

Comment: @VasilyRyabov can you please help ?

Comment: Looks like `dlg_spec.wait('ready', timeout=10)` should help. Maybe you will need `app.wait_cpu_usage_lower()` (it's a method of Application object, be careful!). See [Waiting for Long Operations](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wait_long_operations.html) document.

Comment: OK, I see you've already asked separate question (this is good according to StackOverflow culture). Also StackOverflow appreciates marking correct answers as accepted (gray check box at the left side of answer should work for you).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem should be solved by something like this:

```
app.window(title="Main Window").child_window(title="OK", control_type="Button").exists(timeout=2)
```

Did you read the [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) and [Waiting for Long Operations](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wait_long_operations.html)? They describe all core concepts of pywinauto you need to know for the vast majority of cases.